# Bash variable expansion and brace expansion

Tags: bash

I wonder why I get different results with this:

```
echo {a,b}.txt
a.txt b.txt
```

and this other:

```
A="a,b"                                                          
echo {$A}.txt                                                    
{a,b}.txt
```

I expect both of them to behave the same.

Comment: variable expansion happens after brace expansion in shell

Comment: FYI, `zsh` does as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
A="a,b"
eval echo {$A}.txt
```

you get,

```
a.txt b.txt
```